# AMD ProRender installed but not working

Tags: rendering, add-on, radeon-prorender-render-engine

I just installed AMD's ProRender and I'm trying to experiment with it and see if I like it.  Using Blender 2.8 on Windows 10.

Here's a scene I made, previewed in Cycles:

[image]

Here's the drop down for the Render engines, seems like ProRender is there.  And I didn't have any errors or warnings while installing it or the materials library.
[image]

But when I select the ProRender and either hit "render image" or just chance the viewport mode to rendered.... nothing happens.  Like so:
[image]

In fact, the objects kinda disappeared.  When I hit "render image" the picture never shows up at all.  I never touched any of the default ProRender settings on the right there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check for error messages on the console (*Windows > Toggle System Console*).

Comment: Do you have a supported gpu?

Comment: @rjg  Thanks, the most pertinent info I can see in the console (never knew about that) is errors about "unsupported blend type overlay", "unsupported blend type SCREEN", and a few similar notes.  Too long to paste.  Kinda get the feeling it may be some of the nodes I've used.  

When I just started a brand new Blend File with the default cube in it, the ProRender works.  Must have been some of the nodes I used with Cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, to use the ProRender you have to change all the materials. This is because most of usual Blender shader nodes don't work or work incorrectly in ProRender. Instead, the render engine provides many own material nodes, and the most popular of them is `RPR Uber` shader which is used for PBR (Physically Based Rendering) and can do multiple things at once: diffuse shading, reflection, refraction, light emitting, transparency, etc.

More information about these provided nodes is available in [the shading section of ProRender documentation](https://radeon-pro.github.io/RadeonProRenderDocs/plugins/blender/shading.html).

To make switching from Blender’s internal render engines to ProRender easier, the developers provide [the Material Library with lots of materials](https://radeon-pro.github.io/RadeonProRenderDocs/plugins/matlib/materials.html) ready to use in Blender with ProRender. The Library can be installed and used in Blender on any OS.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking at this later, per the comment section:  the nodes I had used in Cycles were causing trouble.  When I open a new default scene ProRender worked.

Comment: Can you be more specific which nodes weren't working?

Comment: @J.Bakker hi! I added an answer with explanation of this problem.